# Can you reference assembly with unspecified version at web.config?

Tags: c#, web-config, .net-assembly

Currently I have a custom configuration section type in which I use at web.config. Currently I declared the code like this:

```
<section name="ConfigSectionClass" type=MyAssembly.Namespace.ConfigSectionClass, MyAssembly.Namespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f1259434f366e2a5, processorArchitecture=MSIL/>
```

The assembly is installed at GAC.

Currently it has `Version=1.0.0.0` specified, the version of assembly. In my scenario I need to reference the assembly without specific version. If I removed the version number, the compile will error because cannot load the assembly.

Is there any possible solution to reference an assembly without specific version at `web.config`?

Comment: Sorry but **why** you have to omit assembly version? It'll be resolved to right version at run-time...

Comment: @Adriano The library is custom-built inside. In medium-range time (say in several months) I can imagine the version to be different and I want the web config to retrieve the latest version.

Comment: It will by itself if you replace old version with new one (but if this is what you need then why you put it in the GAC?)

Comment: @Adriano: The library is shared, you can call it as a framework or enterprise library. Is there any other way to share library without GAC? Of course I already tried assembly resolver, but it does not being called during mvc's using namespace directive, leaving my application in error.

Answer (score 0):

You use a strongly named.A strongly named assembly consists of four attributes that uniquely identify the assembly

1. FullName
2. Version
3. Culture
4. PublicKey

Note when we have public key so we signed assembly.and we can not sign assembly without version number.

without version number `CLR` how can find the assembly if we have two assembly that have same name?

Comment: This may be sound ignorant, but why if I want the behavior to match the `references` at project level one? With the `specific version` set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem, but sometimes problems with the specific versions can be caused by external libraries requiring different versions of one and the same assembly.

You can have a "binding redirect" to handle cases when libraries require different versions of one and the same DLL.

Yet, you should define the destination assembly version.